# Connect to Ubuntu Server over SSH and having root permissions

Tags: server, nautilus, ssh, wordpress

Is there a way to connect to Ubuntu Server from a desktop Ubuntu using Nautilus, and having root privileges when you connect? I need that, because I have a Wordpress website on the server, and I need to change file permissions.

Right now I am connecting to the server using Nautilus, then CTRL+L, and then this:

```
ssh://username@ipaddress
```

And if I try to change some permissions of files, I get 'permission denied'.

How can I have permissions when connected this way, so I can make file changes?

Comment: And why not  `ssh username@host` in a terminal?

Comment: because I need file manager with UI

Comment: If you want to administer some server, it would be good to begin to learn basic command line tool to do it on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, it's not possible normally to log in as root. If you changed your configuration then browse to:

```
ssh://root@host
```

in Nautilus (the file manager).

If it's not possible to login via root in Nautilus, than you have a problem, because you can't change the user in Nautilus.

---

A better way is to connect via:

```
ssh username@host
```

in a terminal.

Become `root` access via:

```
su -
```

and change the permissions or use `sudo` and change your permissions with:

```
sudo chown ...
```

or:

```
sudo chmod ...
```

Comment: yes I know it's possible to connect via terminal, I would like to know if there is a way to do it with file manager with UI, like Nautilus

Comment: Try `ssh://root@host` as I wrote. Normally it's not possible.